# Is a continuous rational function Lipschitz?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, real-algebraic-geometry

Let $f\in \mathbb{R}(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ be a rational function. Suppose that $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R} ^n$. Must it be Lipschitz on the unit ball?

This question might be related to [Are continuous rational functions arc-analytic?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/278008/are-continuous-rational-functions-arc-analytic)

Comment: I don't understand: your hypothesis is that the denominator of $f$ doesn't vanish on $\mathbb{R}^n$, is it? Then its partial differentials w.r.t. the $x_i$ satisfy the same, so they are continuous, so bounded on the compact closed unit ball, so $f$ is Lipschitz there. But that's too obvious, so you must have meant something different: what did I misunderstand?

Comment: @Gro-Tsen. It is not so obvious. The denominator may actually vanish. For instance the rational function $f(x,y)=\frac{x^2y}{x^2+y^2}$ is continuous, though its partial derivatives are only bounded, but not continuous.

Comment: @DenisSerre Ah, OK. I would say that this function “has a continuous extension” to $\mathbb{R}^n$, not that it *is* continuous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the polynomial
$p(x,y)=(y^3-x^5)^2+(y-x^2)^8$ in the neighborhood of $(0,0)$. Apart from the strip $y^3/x^5\in(1/2,2)$, it is bounded from below by $C(x^2+y^2)^5$; within the strip it is bounded by $C|x|^{40/3}$, and this estimate is sharp. So the function
$$
  \frac{(x^2+y^2)^7}{p(x,y)}
$$
has a continuous extension, but on the curve $y^3=x^5$ it behaves like $x^{2/3}(1+o(1))$, hence it is non-Lipschitz in any neighborhood of $(0,0)$.